# autopopulate from user django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to make a form for updating user accounts in Django that is autopopulated with the current account data for that particular user.  I can do this with HTML, but would rather find a way to make it work using Django's form system.  I can't use Django's built-in user management due to certain constraints and am having to construct my own. I'm lost on where to start with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a normal form (sublassing `forms.Form`), pass data in using the `initial` keyword argument to your form constructor:

```
# forms.py
class MyUserForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(...
    first_name = forms.CharField(...
    ...

# views.py
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Process form
    form = MyUserForm(request.POST)
    ...
else:
    form = MyUserForm(initial={
        'username': request.user.username,
        'first_name': request.user.first_name,
        ...
    }
...
```

An even easier way, though, is using [Django's ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/). Something like:

```
# forms.py
class MyUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

# views.py
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    ...
else:
    form = MyUserForm(instance=request.user)
...
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like it will do it, however, I'm getting this error when trying to load my form:

'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Trying to figure that out now.

Comment: Make sure this code only fires if the user is logged in! Either use the [`@login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) (if the whole view only makes sense for authenticated users) or test `if request.user.is_authenticated()` manually if you want to handle the unauthenticated case yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Read the forms chapter of [The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/) online, for free. Then look into [initial_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) passed to forms. That should get you rolling.